# Are there any Facebook apps that could allow me to reply by email?

Tags: facebook, webapp-rec

I know it is possible to receive your Facebook messages via email.

I would like to reply by email, but Facebook doesn't allow me to do this and instead returns a delivery failure.

Comment: They have never allowed anyone to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Facebook now has "Facebook email" (your vanity name after the www.facebook.com/ followed by @facebook.com). You can send to others at facebook using that address from your normal email client.

Update: Facebook removed said feature. See comments.

Comment: You also reply to a message you received by just replying to the email containing the Facebook message

Comment: Unfortunately this stopped working for me on 8/10/14. Now messages have their Reply To set to noreply <noreply@facebookmail.com>.

Comment: Facebook recently removed the email functionality. Not enough users, I suspect. And fits better in their Messenger app plans.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any Facebook apps that provide the functionality you're after.

As far as I can tell, you can only reply to **status updates** via e-mail.  That's what the link from JoshMock's answer refers to.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to make this work would be an XMPP to email gateway.  Then you could add facebook messages as if it were a normal POP or IMAP email account.

Bonus feature: auto-replace the reply-to address with an email address, for any matching name.

Answer (score 0):

[As of late last year you could](http://www.downloadsquad.com/2009/12/15/facebook-enables-reply-via-email-to-status-updates/) if you set your options on Facebook to send you an email when you get a message. But they have a history of turning this feature on and off, from what I hear, so no guarantees.

Comment: I can confirm this works. I do it all the time. you can reply to anything that is sent to your email, Comments and messages in inbox.

Comment: My messages say: To reply to this message, follow the link below: http://www.facebook.com/n/?extraInfo. I will try this when I get an opportunity

Comment: I just tried replying to a *message* via email. It doesn't work